# How can you force Apps Script Properties Storage to create new line?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to store a KEY file in the Google Apps Script PropertiesService, but the issue is that the KEY contains new line character `\n` that the PropertiesService does not transform it into new line. Because of this, the KEY is invalid and can not be used to connect to Google Services.

Edit: Seems that the PropertiesService is escaping the string, but using unescape does not help out.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found a way, I blame this on the slow morning :)

If anyone else having same problem, my solution was this regex to replace all the occurrences in the string:

```
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("key").replace(/\\n/g, "\n");
```